# Changing the kernel header version for a Buildroot Raspberry Pi default configuration

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, buildroot

I've successfully used buildroot (Buildroot 2016.05-git-01014-g4896b7c) with the raspberypi_defconfig to build a Raspberry Pi bootable image. This default configuration is set to use kernel header version 4.1.5 and it boots the Pi successfully.

My goal is to build a Blue Tooth driver for the Raspberry Pi but the code available requires a version of the kernel headers greater than 4.2.x. So I've modified buildroot's .config file to use a custom version of the kernel header 4.4.x series with the following (https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git) URL of custom repository                                                     (36bb5f17fc320d38d4e887aae8ff13806bb0f672) Custom repository version. This version was recently merged from the remote tracking branch 'stable/linux-4.4.y' into rpi-4.4.y. I've made **no** other changes to the .config file.

The Buildroot 'make' completes without error but the resultant image won't boot the Raspberry Pi.

Build using : Linux version 4.4.8 (ed@linux-dev) (gcc version 4.9.3 (Buildroot 2016.05-git-01014-g4896b7c)

During boot it only gets as far as the splash screen.

My question are:

1) Am I being too naive to expect the image based on the 4.4.8 kernel headers to boot at all?

2) What strategy can I use to try and diagnose why it won't boot?

3) What do others developers do in these circumstances?

I will appreciate your help with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try the latest Buildroot master branch, we have very recently updated the raspberrypi_defconfig to the 4.4.8 kernel, and it has been successfully tested.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but again the boot only gets a far as the splash screen. I'm not using any DT and the zImage I'm using has no trailer (checked with knlinfo). I've tried a second Raspberry Pi but that won't boot either.

Comment: Okay found the problem. The build is okay, it was an outdated procedure I was using to copy the files to the boot partition. I was missing the bcm2708-rpi-*.dtb files. With the dtb files in place it now boots.